# Get the process with apt-get lock

Tags: apt, process

How Can I get the Process information of the process which is holding apt-get lock?

Comment: You are right. Future readers may refer that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it's a dpkg process, so `sudo lsof | grep 'dpkg/lock'`

The output will be something like this:

```
apt-get   23126                   root    4uW     REG               8,18            0    3277485 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

And in my case, the apt-get process is holding the lock.  pid 23126.

If nothing comes back as holding it open, then someone may have interrupted a package download or install and it wasn't able to clean up the lock.

If you want info on that process you could `ps -f -p 23126`

Or, putting it all together, `ps -f -p $(sudo lsof | grep 'dpkg/lock' | awk '{print $1}')`

Or use pstree and show the parents:

```
pstree -s $(sudo lsof | grep 'dpkg/lock' | awk '{print $1}')
```

Comment: Will it always be dpkg process? Even if installation is done using software centre?

Comment: Pretty sure the software center uses dpkg in the background.  You could use pstree to see the parents/children of the process in qustion.  Updated answer.  And it will always be that lock, if that's what you mean...